# Как записать в переменную вывод консоли (cmd)?

Tags: python

Есть такой код:

```
command = "ipconfig"
answer = os.system(command)
```

В консоли PyCharm'а появляется ответ cmd:

```
DNS-���䨪� ������祭�� . . . . . : 
IPv4-����. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.4
��᪠ ����� . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
�᭮���� ��. . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Ethernet adapter ������祭�� �� �����쭮� ��:
����ﭨ� �।�. . . . . . . . : �।� ��।�� ������㯭�.
DNS-���䨪� ������祭�� . . . . . : 

�㭭���� ������ Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

����ﭨ� �।�. . . . . . . . : �।� ��।�� ������㯭�.
DNS-���䨪� ������祭�� . . . . . : 

�㭭���� ������ ������祭�� �� �����쭮� ��* 12:

����ﭨ� �।�. . . . . . . . : �।� ��।�� ������㯭�.
DNS-���䨪� ������祭�� . . . . . : 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Мне нужно все это записать в переменную answer. Но вместо вывода cmd, в нее записывается просто нолик "0".

*я так понял это этот нолик: Process finished with exit code 0*

Мне нужно записать в answer именно содержимое ответа cmd

*и еще. Что не так с кодировкой? Почему рус символы не отображаются? *

Comment: Используйте `subprocess.run(    )`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
# coding utf-8    
# Предыдущая строка меняет кодировку   на   utf-8   
import subprocess
command = "ipconfig"
output = subprocess.check_output(command)
print ouput
```